# Fatal Error After Adding Delay to Array Append

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a simple blackjack app and am currently working on adding a delay to make the cards appear after clicking the deal button. So when you click deal, the cards don't all appear at once, they go one at a time. To do this I am trying to use DispatchQueue to add the delay. My deal button is as follows:

```
func deal(deck: inout [Card]){
        for dealRound in 1...2{
            var dealCard = deck.last
            deck.removeLast()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
                player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
            }
            //player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
            switch dealCard!.rank {
            case 1:
                player1.cardScore += 1
                player1.hasAce = true
            case 11,12,13:
                player1.cardScore += 10
            default:
                player1.cardScore += dealCard!.rank
            }
            dealCard = deck.last
            deck.removeLast()
            dealer.hand.append(dealCard!)
            //If dealRound == 2, dealing upcard to dealer so include that in score
            //Otherwise the down card is not included in the score until after the downcard is revealed
            if dealRound == 2{
                switch dealCard!.rank {
                case 1:
                    dealer.cardScore += 1
                    dealer.hasAce = true
                case 11,12,13:
                    dealer.cardScore += 10
                default:
                    dealer.cardScore += dealCard!.rank
                }
            }
        }
        isDealt = true
    }
```

And player1 is a @state variable of a player class. The images to display the cards is:

```
if isDealt{
                            Image(player1.hand[0].suit.rawValue + String(player1.hand[0].rank) ).resizable().frame(width:120, height:160)
                            Image(player1.hand[1].suit.rawValue + String(player1.hand[1].rank) ).resizable().frame(width:120, height:160).offset(x: 40, y: -40)
                        }
```

When I run the program with the DispatchQueue delay, I get "Fatal Error: Index out of range" when trying to access player1.hand[0] for the image. Is there a different way I should be trying to add a delay as described? I am not sure how it is indexing out of range because the card should be appended to the hand if the deal function returns. I have looked at other posts and they use DispatchQueue to update state variables but they are usually booleans, so does this not work with what I am trying to do?

Comment: You're setting `isDealt = true` before the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` takes place, so it's expected that the `hand` would be empty. You should check `hand` for the number of elements you are attempting to reference before you try to access them -- otherwise, you'll get a crash like you're experiencing.

Comment: So DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter will wait 2 seconds before executing the code in that block, but will continue executing the rest of the program while it is waiting those 2 seconds? I think this is my misunderstanding. I thought it will wait 2 seconds, execute the array append, and then return and continue the program.

Comment: That is correct: the rest of the program keeps executing.

Answer (score 0):

to wait at:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
            player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
        }
```

you could replace it with:

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)  // <-- everything will wait here for 2 sec
player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
```

Comment: Calling `sleep` on the main thread will freeze the app during that time period and not accept user interaction at all. It is generally not recommended.