# SwiftUI adding delay to view from inside function call

Tags: swiftui, delay

I am trying to code a blackjack deal button where the cards are dealt like so on hitting the button:

Deal face-up card to a player, delay 1 second

Deal face down card to a dealer, delay 1 second

Deal face-up card to a player, delay 1 second

Deal face-up card to a dealer, delay 1 second

My struggle is getting the delays in between each dealt card to make it seem more realistic as opposed to all 4 cards just appearing upon hitting the button. I currently have a deal function defined as so that is called when the deal button is hit:

```
            for dealRound in 1...2{
                var dealCard = deck.last
                deck.removeLast()
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false){ (_) in
                    player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
                }
                //player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
                switch dealCard!.rank {
                case 1:
                    player1.cardScore += 1
                    player1.hasAce = true
                case 11,12,13:
                    player1.cardScore += 10
                default:
                    player1.cardScore += dealCard!.rank
                }
                dealCard = deck.last
                deck.removeLast()
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false){ (_) in
                    dealer.hand.append(dealCard!)
                }
                //If dealRound == 2, dealing upcard to dealer so include that in score
                //Otherwise the down card is not included in the score until after the downcard is revealed
                if dealRound == 2{
                    switch dealCard!.rank {
                    case 1:
                        dealer.cardScore += 1
                        dealer.hasAce = true
                    case 11,12,13:
                        dealer.cardScore += 10
                    default:
                        dealer.cardScore += dealCard!.rank
                    }
                }
            }
            isDealt = true
        }
```

However, when I hit the deal button, there is a delay and then all 4 cards appear at once. The images for the cards are defined as:
`Image(dealer.hand[1].suit.rawValue + String(dealer.hand[1].rank) ).resizable().frame(width:120, height:160).offset(x: 40, y: -40)`
I use dealer.hand[0] and player.hand[0] and [1] to show the other cards. The player and dealer are State variables of a Player class. I have tried using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter and sleep(1) but have run into similar problems. The only thing I can think to do would be to create 4 separate state Boolean variables and have them set to true after a delay (in a separate function from the deal) so the cards will appear. However, this seems like a poor way of doing it and I feel as though there may be a way similar to what I am trying but can't figure out.

In short: how would I go about adding a delay to an image appearing where the image is dependent on a @State class's array being appended to in a function call?

Comment: so my answer to your last question did not work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657142/fatal-error-after-adding-delay-to-array-append

Comment: The same as in your last question, the lines after `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { ... }` run immediately -- they don't want for the `Timer`. If you want something to happen *after* the `Timer`, it has to go inside the Timer's closure (or call a function from inside that closure).

Comment: I am putting it in the closure like so: ```Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
                    player1.hand.append(dealCard!)
                }```. However, this does a 1 second delay and then displays all 4 cards at once, which is not what I am going for. Checking for the elements did help with the error from my previous question but I still can't get it to do what I want it to do. My logic for my deal function is that for each dealRound loop, it will pause for 1 second before it appends to the hand. This is what I am trying to accomplish.